# net.inet.tcp.blackhole option on Fedora

Tags: security, fedora, sysctl

[This link of freebsdblog.org](http://www.freebsdblog.org/51/reduce-server-visibility/) suggests a configuration option for FreeBSD that tells the system to drop all packages arriving from the network to a closed port and thus somewhat securing your system and also saving some upload bandwidth as well as cpu time. These are the shell commands to run:

```
sysctl net.inet.tcp.blackhole=2
sysctl net.inet.udp.blackhole=1
```

and this you should also insert to the **/etc/sysctl.conf** file so the settings survive a server reboot:

```
net.inet.tcp.blackhole=2
net.inet.udp.blackhole=1
```

That's cool so far, but. My Fedora Linux box keeps saying

```
error: "net.inet.tcp.blackhole" is an unknown key
```

The quoted parameter names are not listed under **/proc/sys**, and not returned by **sysctl -a**.

I found no reference to this problem online. Am I missing something? Do these parameter names differ under Fedora? Do I need some additional package to have this functionality?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Removed freebsd tag

Answer (score 2):

You do realise that Fedora isn't FreeBSD, don't you?  To do something similar to this in a Linux distribution, just set the policy on your firewall to be DROP.

Comment: Yup I do realize. I just thought the same solution could as well exist in both cases. Anyway, thanks very much for the solution!